# Why i can't return a Json Object?

Tags: jquery, json, return

I'm getting undefined when i try to return the oject from the function. And i'm pretty sure that the object is not empty otherwise `alert(response.html);` shouldn't be working.

```
var Core = {
    "Ajax" : function(url, data){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: host + url,
            data: data,
            success: function(json){
                var response = $.parseJSON(json);
                if(response.status == "200"){
                    alert(response.html);
                    return response;
                }
                else{
                    alert(response.html);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably misunderstanding the concept of Ajax, which is asynchronous.

The success callback will be called by the browser when the request has completed. Anything you return in the success callback, will simply vanish.

It is not possible to return something to the line of code that is *initiating* the request - when the success callback fires, you are already past that line.

Comment: Point. Houwever i've tried it Asyncronously usint the async option and still doesn't work.

Comment: @Sein `async: false` indeed makes it synchonous, but it doesn't work that way either - `$.ajax()` will always return the `XMlHTTPRequest` object, never the return value from the success callback. You could make your success callback to set it in the XMLHTTP object and pry the value from in there, but it's probably easier to set a predefined variable `var result = null; $.ajax(....)`

Comment: @Sein: It's asynchronous as it is now.  You can't "return" from AJAX calls, you need to use callback functions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return things from **asynchronous** functions. The function which calls `$.ajax()` returns right after calling it - (almost) always before the response has been received.
**Do whatever you need to do with the response in the `success` callback.**

PS: Add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax arguments and use `json.status` - no need to do the parsing on your own.

Besides that, use Firebug's console to check what you actually get back from the server (`alert()` is **not** a debugger)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return anything from an `$.ajax` call, it's asynchronous.  You need to have it call another callback function and pass it `response`.

Also, you don't need `$.parseJSON(json)`.  Just set `dataType: 'json'` and jQuery'll parse the JSON for you.